# Received 'Boolean Series key will be reindexed to match DataFrame index' warning when creating a new data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, boolean-indexing

Is there any potential downside to using the following code to create a new data frame, wherein I'm specifying very specific information from the original data frame I want to see in the new data frame.

`df_workloc = (df[df['WorkLoc'] == 'Home'][df['CareerSat'] == 'Very satisfied'][df['CurrencySymbol'] == 'USD'][df['CompTotal'] >= 50000])`

I used the 2019 Stack Overflow survey data. As such:

**WorkLoc** specifies where a respondent works.

**CareerSat** specifies a respondent's career satisfaction.

**CurrencySymbol** specifies what currency a respondent gets paid in.

**CompTotal** specifies what a respondent's total compensation is.

If anyone has a cleaner, more efficient way of achieving a data frame with refined / specific information I'd love to see it. One thing I'd like to do is specify a Compensation total **CompTotal** of >= 50000 and <=75000 in the same line. However, I get an error when I tried to include the second boolean.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: hi @Tweep, are these conditions independent? that is is it either of the conditions, or all of the conditions must be met? also, kindly share a small sample of ur dataset that reflects ur question, with ur expected output. pls, data, not pics or links.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need chain conditions with & for bitwise `AND` and filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing), also for last condition use [`Series.between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html):

```
m1 = df['WorkLoc'] == 'Home'
m2 = df['CareerSat'] == 'Very satisfied'
m3 = df['CurrencySymbol'] == 'USD'
m4 = df['CompTotal'].between(50000, 75000)
df_workloc = df[m1 & m2 & m3 & m4]
```

Or for one line solution:

```
df_workloc = df[(df['WorkLoc'] == 'Home') &
                (df['CareerSat'] == 'Very satisfied') &
                (df['CurrencySymbol'] == 'USD') &
                 df['CompTotal'].between(50000, 75000)]
```